# mysql PDO multi parameter insert statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i dont know what is wrong.. i've seen a lot of different ways to do it, can some one tell me what the hell is wrong with this.. its throwing this error "ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc) VALUES ('30.59','blue shirt','a really cool blue shirt')' at line 1". I have tried it multiple ways and its the same result..

```
<?php
$title = 'blue shirt';
$desc = 'a really cool blue shirt';
$price = 30.59;

$user = 'foo';
$pass = 'Bar';

try{
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=examplehost;dbname=exampledb_name',$user,$pass);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
if(!$conn){
    echo"couldnt connect to db";
}else {
    echo 'connected like a boss!!' . '<br>';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO 68_items (price, title, desc) VALUES (:price,:title,:desc)");
    if(!$stmt->execute(array(
            ':price' => $price,
            ':title' => $title,
            ':desc' => $desc))
    ) {
        echo'statment failed';
    }else {
        echo 'statment success, ' .  $stmt->rowCount() . 'rows affected.';
    }
}
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: We could ask you the same question. What is wrong with your code? Error? Nothing? Doesn't do what's expected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`desc` is a [reserved word in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) so you should use backticks to escape it:

```
"INSERT INTO 68_items (price, title, `desc`) VALUES (:price,:title,:desc)"
```

Comment: +1 I was just typing 'backticks' when you posted your answer :)

Comment: that's insane... i guess its the breaks of learning web design... thank you, i've been going at this for about 2hrs..